# Mismatch error at compilation stage during siesta 4.1b4 installation

Tags: command-line

I have an error in the compilation stage during Siesta 4.1b4 installation, how to solve the issue

```
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (COMPLEX(8)/REAL(8)). /home/sally/siesta-4.1-b4/Src/diag2k.F:310:55: 209 | call cdiag(Haux,Saux,2*nuotot,2*nuo,2*nuotot,eo(1,ik),psi, | 2 ...... 310 | call cdiag(Haux,Saux,2*nuotot,2*nuo,2*nuotot,caux,psi, | 1 Error: Type mismatch between actual argument
```

Comment: https://gitlab.com/siesta-project/siesta/-/issues/103